# iOS framework: what is ABT (ABTViewSelectorComponent, ABTWeakValue, ABTDestructonomicon, etc.)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, libraries

I'm doing some memory profiling on Instruments.

I'm seeing allocations of objects of the `ABT` framework: `ABTViewSelectorComponent`, `ABTWeakValue`, `ABTDestructonomicon`, `ABTStyleForest`, `ABTResultsElementShownEntry`, `ABTResultsElementHiddenEntry`, etc.

Does anybody know an easy way of finding which framework do this objects come from?

I'm not sure if it's a private Apple framework or any of our 3rd party frameworks (we are using over a dozen frameworks through Cocoapods).

I could go and use `nm` on all frameworks hunting for these symbols, but ideally I'd like a more automated way of finding out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it by using the `strings` utility on my 3rd party frameworks (`nm` didn't seem to work).

The culprit is *Apptimize*.